# How can you put two parameters in a switch statement?

Tags: c++, switch-statement

I've tried to do this but it always outputs the default case, and yes I've set the k and j to 1 and 3

```
switch(k,j){
case 1&&3:
    cout << "1 3 \n";
    break;
default:
    cout << "invalid \n";
    break;
```

Comment: You can't, as simple as that. `1 && 3` is an expression whose result is `1`.

Comment: @LittlePiggie Write a proposal to the C++ Standard Committee.:)

Comment: You could use another layer of switches inside the first one or try to pack both values in a single long maybe.

Answer (score 6):

The statement switch is not a function. It does not have parameters.

In this switch statement

```
switch(k,j)
```

there is used an expression with the comma operator. The result of the expression is the value of the operand j. As the expression does not have a side effect then it is equivalent to

```
switch( j )
```

What you mean is the following

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int k = 1, j = 3;

    switch ( k )
    {
    case 1:
        switch ( j )
        {
        case 3:                
            std::cout << "k and j are equal to correspondingly to "
                      << 1 << " and " << 3 << '\n';
            break;
        default:
            std::cout << "Invalid values.\n";
            break;
        }
        break;            
    default:
        std::cout << "Invalid values.\n";
        break;
    }            
}
```

The program output is

```
k and j are equal to correspondingly to 1 and 3
```

Or in C++ 17 you may declare the variables in the switch statement like

```
switch ( int k = 1, j = 3; k )
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try to transform the two values in a single one. I don't know how big can be the values `k`and `j` , but you can make some thing like

```
int newValue = k*1000+j; 
switch(newValue){
case 1003:
    cout << "1 3 \n";
    break;
default:
    cout << "invalid \n";
    break;
}
```